# Rotate two parallel lines to create an X

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rotation, graphics2d

The following code is the code that I am using to rotate two rectangles is below

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);

//r1
Rectangle2D r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 50, 4);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
g2d.fill(r1);

//r3
Rectangle2D r3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 25, 50, 4);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));
g2d.fill(r3);
```

This create something which looks like this

[image]

Whereas I am trying to create something which looks like this

[image]

This occurs since when the rectangles are rotated, they are both rotated around the point `0,0`. To fix that I tried using [rotate(double theta, double x, double y)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate-double-double-double-). However I am having trouble using that correctly. For example when I have tried

```
Rectangle2D r3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 25, 50, 4);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90), 25, 25);
```

or

```
Rectangle2D r3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 25, 50, 4);
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90), 0, 25);
```

I get similar undesired results when both the rectangles were being rotated around the point `0,0`. I would appreciate any help if fixing my problem.

If you are wondering why I have done it like this, it is because I am hoping to make a effect similar to when you click on the 3 parallel lines seen [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index2.html) by the time I finish coding the graphic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this can be done with some relatively simple maths. As the shape I am trying to make is a perfect X.

To work out the position for the rectangle we can use [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

[image]

The image above shows two steps.

```
Translation [2√2, 0] from the point [0, 0]
Rotate 45deg from the point [2√2, 0]
```

Next we need to work out the minimum point of this rectangle. Again we can use [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

[image]

This tells us where the top point of the second rectangle will be

```
Difference in height: 4 - 2√2
Bottom of line when straight: [0, 27√2 + (4 - 2√2)] = [0, 4 + 25√2]
Top of line when straight: [0, 25√2]
```

Finally we can put in the last rectangle starting at `[0, 0]`

```
Translation [0, 25√2] from the point [0, 0]
Rotate -45deg from the point [0, 25√2]
```

Now that the theory is out of the way, what does this look like in code? It looks similar to the code below

```
//Values
final static double[] r1Points = {2.828427125, 0}; //Equivilant 2√2
final static double[] r3Points = {0, 35.35533906}; //Equivilant 25√2
final static int[] widthNHeight = {50, 4}; //Width then height
final static double angle = 45.0; //Angle to rotate lines

//Declaring the rectangles
Rectangle2D r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(r1Points[0], r1Points[1], widthNHeight[0], widthNHeight[1]);
Rectangle2D r3 = new Rectangle2D.Double(r3Points[0], r3Points[1], widthNHeight[0], widthNHeight[1]);

//r1
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), r1Points[0], r1Points[1]); //Rotates graphic for first rectangle
g2d.fill(r1);

//r3
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-angle), r1Points[0], r1Points[1]); //Rotates the graphic back to straight
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-angle), r3Points[0], r3Points[1]); //Rotates graphic for second rectangle
g2d.fill(r3);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Cross extends JPanel {

    private Rectangle2D rectangle;

    Cross() {
        rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 50, 4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
        g2.translate(5, 5);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
        g2.fill(rectangle);

        g2.setTransform(at);
        g2.translate(5, 5 + Math.sqrt(2) * 25);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(-45));
        g2.fill(rectangle);

        g2.setTransform(at);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cross");
        frame.add(new Cross());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(128, 128);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



}
```

Although I think I might have done mistake somewhere with maths (it looks somewhat odd), this should give you an idea.